# UIScrollView -zoomToRect:animated: and CGPoint conversion between views

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have got a `UIScrollView` **A** with a subview **B**, (which itself is a subview of the contentView **D** of `A` -- so **B** is **NOT** the contentView of the scrollview `A`) which has a subview, let's call it **C**.

```
+------------------------+
| A                      |
|                        |
|  +-------------------+ |
|  |D (=contentView)   | |
|  |  +-----------+    | |
|  |  | B         |    | |
|  |  |   +--+    |    | |
|  |  |   |C |    |    | |
|  |  |   +--+    |    | |
|  |  +-----------+    | |
|  +-------------------+ |
+------------------------+
```

I would like the scrollView to zoom exactly so that C fills my iPhone's screen, or at least display it to me as large as possible. 
I cannot wrap my head around how the `zoomScale` of the scrollview before the zoom (let's assume I zoom in when the scrollview is already zoomed in and has a zoomScale of 2.45). 
So the first question is, does the zoomScale affect the rect that the UIScrollView zooms into?

My second question regards CGPoint conversion. iOS has some built in functions to convert CGPoints/CGRects between views, but I simply can't produce anything productive from the given references.

Here is what I intended to do:

1) Convert **C**'s origin to **A**'s coordinate system:

```
CGPoint originConvertedToAsCoordinateSystem = [self convertPoint:C.frame.origin toView:A];
```

2) Zoom to the rect with the given origin of **C**:

```
//shortened for the purpose of readability
CGPoint p = originConvertedToAsCoordinateSystem;

CGRect zoomRect = CGRectMake(p.x,p.y,C.frame.size.width,C.frame.size.height);
[A zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
```

I have neglected the value of **A**'s`zoomScale` in my given example as I do not really know whether to multiply or divide the value.

Comment: Not sure I understand your questions. Just a note: the rect to zoom must be in the content view's coordinate space (I assume it is subview B) so you do not need to to convert C.frame, just use it as is.

Comment: @yurish I just want the scroll view `A` to zoom to the origin of view `C`. I cannot 'just use `C`'s frame' because its frame is in `B`'s coordinate system. So I would have to convert `C`'s origin to the coordinate space of `A`. The

Comment: Sorry, but "zoom to origin" (which is point, not a rectangle) just does not make much sense to me. Also have you read zoomToRect method description? It explicitly states that "The rectangle should be in the coordinate space of the view returned by viewForZoomingInScrollView:". The view in your case must be B, not the scroll view itself as you are trying to do. Anyway see the answer.

Comment: @yurish Oh, sorry, yeah you were right... But the problem is, `B` really is NOT the content view, but a subview of the content view...

Comment: From your picture B is subview of scroll view A. How the scroll view can be content view of itself? Either your description is not accurate or you misunderstand what content view is. Which view do you return from viewForZoomingInScrollView? Have you tried the code in the answer?

Comment: @yurish My `contentView` (which I return in `viewForZoomingInScrollView`) is a view `D` and `B` is the subview of it. I updated my question...

Answer (score 1):

**Updated after the question update:**

If you want to programmatically zoom and and scroll the scroll view so that the subview C fills entire scroll view rectangle (scroll view bounds) you need to do following in your view controller:

```
CGRect rectToZoom = [self.D convertRect:self.C.frame fromView:self.B];

[self.scrollView zoomToRect:rectToZoom animated:YES];
```

This is assuming that you return view D as the view to zoom:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.D;
}
```

maximumZoomScale, contentSize and contentInset properties of the scroll view must be large enough to allow the scrolling and zooming (check: try to do what you want manually and see if it is possible).